# VS 2010 Debug expands all projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010. I have a solution with about 10+ different projects. Before starting the app with the debugger I have only one or two of the projects expanded in the Solution Explorer. When I start the app with debugging the Solution Explorer expands all of the projects. My current computer is horribly sluggish so when try to either scroll down the appropriate project or collapse the irrelevant projects it can take a while.

Anyone know if there is a way to get VS 2010 to stop automatically expanding all of the projects when an app starts with debugging?

I did not have this issue with VS 2008 and its been a while but I do not recall this happening with 2005 either.

Comment: There's a collapse all button at the top. Hit that, then scroll.  Also, unload all projects that are accessed rarely.

Comment: The collapse all button is an extension in vs 2010

Comment: Certainly there must be a way to not VS2010 go through the trouble to expand the projects when they weren't expanded to begin with. Sure there is a collapse all button (which I am glad you pointed that out) but it makes little sense for the projects to expand by default anyways